# Docker Java EE container not starting

Tags: jakarta-ee, docker, jms, ibm-cloud

I have a Java EE application using the SQLDB and MQLight services on Bluemix. This is all running within one container. When I start the container I receive the following logs:

```
>[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server icServer has been launched.
?[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/8.5.5.9/lafiles/en.html
>[INFO    ] CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 3.091 seconds
/[INFO    ] CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
c[WARNING ] CWWKS3103W: There are no users defined for the BasicRegistry configuration of ID basic.
;[INFO    ] CWWKS0007I: The security service is starting...
?[INFO    ] CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host localhost  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 9080.
=[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
?[INFO    ] CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint-ssl has been started and is now listening for requests on host localhost  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 9443.
?[INFO    ] SPI-Provider Manifest header found in bundle: com.ibm.ws.xlxp.1.5.3 Bundle:com.ibm.ws.org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-osgi-registry.1.1(id=139)   
6[INFO    ] CWWKS0008I: The security service is ready.
H[INFO    ] CWWKS4105I: LTPA configuration is ready after 0.471 seconds.
a[INFO    ] DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named baseCache initialized successfully.
@[INFO    ] DYNA1071I: The cache provider default is being used.
M[INFO    ] DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
k[AUDIT   ] CWWKI0001I: The CORBA name server is now available at corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809/NameService.
4[INFO    ] CWWKZ0018I: Starting application IC-DEV.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on dataSource[SQLDB].
?[WARNING ] DSRA8020E: Warning: The property 'id' does not exist on the DataSource class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.
[[INFO    ] CWRLS0010I: Performing recovery processing for local WebSphere server (Server).
?[INFO    ] CWRLS0012I: All persistent services have been directed to perform recovery processing for this WebSphere server (Server).
F[INFO    ] WTRN0135I: Transaction service recovering no transactions.
W[INFO    ] CNTR4000I: The IC-DEV.war EJB module in the IC-DEV application is starting.
&[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.security.TokenGeneratorTest interface of the TokenGeneratorTest enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/TokenGeneratorTest!com.ibm.ic.security.TokenGeneratorTest
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.APIServiceRegister interface of the APIServiceRegister enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/APIServiceRegister!com.ibm.ic.api.APIServiceRegister
P[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.WorkloadSchedulerRestController interface of the WorkloadSchedulerRestController enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/WorkloadSchedulerRestController!com.ibm.ic.api.WorkloadSchedulerRestController
,[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.EmergencyTestEndpoints interface of the EmergencyTestEndpoints enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/EmergencyTestEndpoints!com.ibm.ic.api.EmergencyTestEndpoints
H[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.WorkloadSchedulerAssetRemoval interface of the WorkloadSchedulerAssetRemoval enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/WorkloadSchedulerAssetRemoval!com.ibm.ic.api.WorkloadSchedulerAssetRemoval
D[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.emergency.EmergencyRestController interface of the EmergencyRestController enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/EmergencyRestController!com.ibm.ic.api.emergency.EmergencyRestController
T[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.emergency.APIServiceEmergencyWorkflow interface of the APIServiceEmergencyWorkflow enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/APIServiceEmergencyWorkflow!com.ibm.ic.api.emergency.APIServiceEmergencyWorkflow
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.WcmTestEndpoints interface of the WcmTestEndpoints enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/WcmTestEndpoints!com.ibm.ic.api.WcmTestEndpoints
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.BtbTestEndpoints interface of the BtbTestEndpoints enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/BtbTestEndpoints!com.ibm.ic.api.BtbTestEndpoints
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.mdbtest.RestController interface of the RestController enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/RestController!com.ibm.ic.api.mdbtest.RestController
 [INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.wcm.WcmRestController interface of the WcmRestController enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/WcmRestController!com.ibm.ic.api.wcm.WcmRestController
?[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.Service interface of the Service enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/Service!com.ibm.ic.api.Service
,[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.APIServiceAssetRemoval interface of the APIServiceAssetRemoval enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/APIServiceAssetRemoval!com.ibm.ic.api.APIServiceAssetRemoval
8[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.WorkloadSchedulerRegister interface of the WorkloadSchedulerRegister enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/WorkloadSchedulerRegister!com.ibm.ic.api.WorkloadSchedulerRegister

[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.marketops.MoService interface of the MoService enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/MoService!com.ibm.ic.api.marketops.MoService
([INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.marketops.MoRestController interface of the MoRestController enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/MoRestController!com.ibm.ic.api.marketops.MoRestController
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.marketops.MoApiService interface of the MoApiService enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/MoApiService!com.ibm.ic.api.marketops.MoApiService
4[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.APIServiceResumeWorkflow interface of the APIServiceResumeWorkflow enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/APIServiceResumeWorkflow!com.ibm.ic.api.APIServiceResumeWorkflow
t[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.workloadscheduler.WorkloadSchedulerCampaignBriefs interface of the WorkloadSchedulerCampaignBriefs enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/WorkloadSchedulerCampaignBriefs!com.ibm.ic.api.workloadscheduler.WorkloadSchedulerCampaignBriefs
?[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.workloadscheduler.WorkloadSchedulerEmergencyWorkflows interface of the WorkloadSchedulerEmergencyWorkflows enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/WorkloadSchedulerEmergencyWorkflows!com.ibm.ic.api.workloadscheduler.WorkloadSchedulerEmergencyWorkflows
x[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.workloadscheduler.WorkloadSchedulerUpdateWorkflows interface of the WorkloadSchedulerUpdateWorkflows enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/WorkloadSchedulerUpdateWorkflows!com.ibm.ic.api.workloadscheduler.WorkloadSchedulerUpdateWorkflows
p[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.workloadscheduler.WorkloadSchedulerRunRetryQueue interface of the WorkloadSchedulerRunRetryQueue enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/WorkloadSchedulerRunRetryQueue!com.ibm.ic.api.workloadscheduler.WorkloadSchedulerRunRetryQueue
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.api.RegisterService interface of the RegisterService enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/RegisterService!com.ibm.ic.api.RegisterService
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.ProjectBean interface of the Project enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/Project!com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.ProjectBean
?[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.AssetBean interface of the Asset enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/Asset!com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.AssetBean
*[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.ProcessedWorkflowBean interface of the ProcessedWorkflow enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/ProcessedWorkflow!com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.ProcessedWorkflowBean
&[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.RetryQueueListener interface of the RetryQueueListener enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/RetryQueueListener!com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.RetryQueueListener
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.Messenger interface of the Messenger enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/Messenger!com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.Messenger
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.WorkflowBean interface of the Workflow enterprise bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application.  The binding location is: java:global/IC-DEV/Workflow!com.ibm.ic.ejb.bean.WorkflowBean
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The HandlerMDB message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/HandlerMDB activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MoNewCampaignListenerBean message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MoNewCampaignListenerBean activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MoNewBriefListenerBean message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MoNewBriefListenerBean activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBMarketOpsSubmitter message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBMarketOpsSubmitter activation specification.
[WARNING ] CNTR4016W: The message endpoint for the MDBMarketOpsSubmitter message-driven bean cannot be activated because the jms/MarketOpsListener/submitMo destination is not available. The message endpoint will not receive messages until the destination becomes available.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBCreateWCMEmergencyProject message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBCreateWCMEmergencyProject activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBCreateBTBEmergencyWorkflow message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBCreateBTBEmergencyWorkflow activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBResumeWorkflow message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBResumeWorkflow activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBRejectWCMProject message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBRejectWCMProject activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBDeleteWCMProject message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBDeleteWCMProject activation specification.
[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBUpdateWCMEmergencyProjectAfterCreatingBTBEmergencyWorkflow message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBUpdateWCMEmergencyProjectAfterCreatingBTBEmergencyWorkflow activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBRegister message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBRegister activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBAssetRemoval message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBAssetRemoval activation specification.
?[INFO    ] CNTR0180I: The MDBApproveWCMProject message-driven bean in the IC-DEV.war module of the IC-DEV application is bound to the IC-DEV/MDBApproveWCMProject activation specification.
d[INFO    ] CNTR4001I: The IC-DEV.war EJB module in the IC-DEV application has started successfully.
2[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: IC-DEV.
H[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module IC-DEV has been bound to default_host.
X[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/
D[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application IC-DEV started in 2.810 seconds.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/HandlerMDB.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/HandlerMDB and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#HandlerMDB is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MoNewCampaignListenerBean.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MoNewCampaignListenerBean and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MoNewCampaignListenerBean is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MoNewBriefListenerBean.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MoNewBriefListenerBean and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MoNewBriefListenerBean is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MDBCreateWCMEmergencyProject.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MDBCreateWCMEmergencyProject and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MDBCreateWCMEmergencyProject is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MDBCreateBTBEmergencyWorkflow.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MDBCreateBTBEmergencyWorkflow and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MDBCreateBTBEmergencyWorkflow is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MDBResumeWorkflow.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MDBResumeWorkflow and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MDBResumeWorkflow is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MDBRejectWCMProject.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MDBRejectWCMProject and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MDBRejectWCMProject is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MDBDeleteWCMProject.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MDBDeleteWCMProject and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MDBDeleteWCMProject is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MDBUpdateWCMEmergencyProjectAfterCreatingBTBEmergencyWorkflow.
[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MDBUpdateWCMEmergencyProjectAfterCreatingBTBEmergencyWorkflow and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MDBUpdateWCMEmergencyProjectAfterCreatingBTBEmergencyWorkflow is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MDBRegister.
?[WARNING ] J2CA8501E: Property maxConcurrency of configuration element IC-DEV/MDBRegister cannot be set because it is not found on the class com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MDBRegister and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MDBRegister is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MDBAssetRemoval.
?[WARNING ] J2CA8501E: Property maxConcurrency of configuration element IC-DEV/MDBAssetRemoval cannot be set because it is not found on the class com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MDBAssetRemoval and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MDBAssetRemoval is activated.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on IC-DEV/MDBApproveWCMProject.
?[INFO    ] J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification IC-DEV/MDBApproveWCMProject and message driven bean application IC-DEV#IC-DEV.war#MDBApproveWCMProject is activated.
?[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.1, beanValidation-1.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, jca-1.7, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, jdbc-4.1, appSecurity-2.0, jaxrs-2.0, wmqJmsClient-2.0, jpa-2.1, managedBeans-1.0, ejbLite-3.2, ejbHome-3.2, localConnector-1.0, jsonp-1.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, el-3.0, ejbRemote-3.2, jaxb-2.2, mdb-3.2, ejb-3.2, json-1.0, distributedMap-1.0, wasJmsSecurity-1.0].
F[INFO    ] CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 23171.621 seconds.
M[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server icServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
```

When I visit the public IP address for this container I cannot reach the site. Also my application is taking hours to complete the feature update - why is this happening?

Comment: could you please retrieve the container's logs through 
cf ic logs [container-name]
?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the full log. It appears my application has now started, but has taken 23000 seconds, and I am still unable to view the site.

Comment: what do you see when you run 'cf ic ps' ?

Comment: I see the container, its ID, name and status as Running